# Unable to register TkChild class

Tags: php, python-3.x, tcl, tk-toolkit, shell-exec

I try to run a python file with php under Windows from my local server (Wamp) but I get errors

Here is the instruction I execute

```
<?php var_dump(shell_exec("python C:/wamp64/www/ml/main.py 2>&1")); ?>
```

And I get this error at the end of the execution:

```
C:\wamp64\www\summary\stats_full.php:64:string 'Unable to register TclNotifier window class' (length=44)
```

Comment: That's probably a failure at the setup of the very lowest level of the event handling system, where stuff connects to the guts of Windows. It is also very surprising; I've *never* heard of that blowing up before! Does it work in the terminal without PHP wrapping it? (Reproducible failures of this sort mean there's a bug to fix; right now, it is a "can't happen" case that is happening...)

Comment: At the very least, without narrowing down whether the problem is in PHP, Python, Tkinter, Tk or Tcl, making progress on what to do about it is tough. That's a lot of production code in the mix! Something is putting things in a weird state, but I have no idea what. (That message is in a `Tcl_Panic()` call inside the Windows-specific part of Tk if I remember right, but I don't understand that bit of the code and its assumptions.)

Comment: It works fine in the terminal but not when I run it in PHP.

Comment: I solved my problem by following this tutorial 
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-to-fix-error-message-class-not-registered-in/83c9ee7b-a919-4398-b4e3-ed5028311107